# unable to send shift-end with Win32::GuiTest

Tags: perl, win32gui

I would need to automate some keyboard entries inside my perl script. For this, I use  [Win32::GuiTest](http://search.cpan.org/~karasik/Win32-GuiTest-1.63/lib/Win32/GuiTest.pm) module. 
This works fine for all entries I need except for shift-end.

Here's what I send

```
Win32::GuiTest::SendKeys("+{END}");
```

but it seems that it only takes the {END}.

The weird thing is that

```
Win32::GuiTest::SendKeys("+(some text)");
```

works fine and sends `SOME TEXT`

In fact, I am unable to do `+{}` commands, it always take only the key inside the `{}`

On the other hand, commands with `^` (ctrl) or `%` (alt) work fine for example `Win32::GuiTest::SendKeys("%{F4}")` closes the window

does anybody would know why?

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried `+{35}` ?

Comment: just tried, It behave the same than with +{END}, it seems to only take the {35} into consideration
but thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, anyway, maybe it is of help to somebody...

Shift{foo} commands like Shift{End} need to be performed with low-level keybd_event via the SendRawKey wrapper. So this is what you are looking for:

```
    SendRawKey(VK_LSHIFT, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY);
    SendKeys('{END}');
    SendRawKey(VK_RSHIFT, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP);
    SendRawKey(VK_LSHIFT, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP);
```

Full sample (copies a complete line into the clipboard):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Win32::Clipboard;
use Win32::GuiTest qw (:ALL);   # Win32-GuiTest-1.63 used

print "place cursor now...\n"; sleep(5); print get_line();

sub get_line {

    Win32::Clipboard()->Empty();

    SendKeys('{HOME}');
    SendRawKey(VK_LSHIFT, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY);
    SendKeys('{END}');
    SendRawKey(VK_RSHIFT, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP);
    SendRawKey(VK_LSHIFT, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP);

    SendKeys('^c');
    return Win32::Clipboard()->GetText();
}
```